# How can I write multiple data to firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem about writing multiple data to firebase. I have three different arrays, one int and I have to take uid's child(adress) and uid's name. In simple way I want to make orders node and I have to write all these datas in same node. I tried to make it set value but it takes only the last one other will deleted. I can't find any way to fix it. How can I solve ?

Here my code:

```
func firebaseConfigForUserAndAdress() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    // these are my arrays
    print(siparisEdilenUrunleriTutanArray)
    print(siparisEdilenFiyatlariTutanArray)
    print(siparisEdilenCountlariTutanArray)



     // values for only try... 
    var values = siparisEdilenUrunleriTutanArray + siparisEdilenFiyatlariTutanArray


    let refOrder = Database.database().reference().child("orders").child("kullanicilar").child(uid)

    refOrder.setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to update database values with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }


            //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    refOrder.setValue(["urun sayilari" : self.siparisEdilenCountlariTutanArray])
}
```

How can I write these datas to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but think you may be looking for `childByAutoId()`. When you call `childByAutoId()` on a location, Firebase will generate a unique ID under that location where you can then write the data.

For you that'd look something like:

```
let refOrder = Database.database().reference().child("orders").child("kullanicilar").child(uid)

refOrder.childByAutoId().setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
  ...
```

Comment: I saw that method at docs but its gave me lots of auto ıd. Is this correct way to do this?

Comment: `childByAutoId` will generate a unique ID each time you call it. If that's not what you want (but you also don't want to overwrite the existing data each time), you'll need to figure out how often to generate new IDs. So instead of describing the behavior you *don't* want, try to describe what you *do* want, then implement that.